# Avast threat neutralized when building tika-parser-pkg-module-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar

Tags: java, maven, apache-tika

so I've just download tika repo from github and I was trying to build it.
But the build failed due to

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:3.1.0:install (default-install) on project tika-parser-pkg-module: Failed to install artifact org.apache.tika:tika-parser-pkg-module:jar:tests:2.7.1-SNAPSHOT: C:\Users\Massimo\tika\tika-parsers\tika-parsers-standard\tika-parsers-standard-modules\tika-parser-pkg-module\target\tika-parser-pkg-module-2.7.1-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar (Impossibile completare l'operazione. Il file contiene un virus o software potenzialmente indesiderato)
```

and avast says

[image]

How can I be sure it's a false positive??

Comment: In fact the test jar is suspicious by Avast. Probably one test resource (.pdf, .png, etc.). Sometimes it happens like: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-3555?jql=project%20%3D%20TIKA%20AND%20text%20~%20virus
If you don't need the snapshot version, just use 2.7.0. from central repository. Otherwise check the source code to detect which file is affected and open a ticket on Tika's JIRA

Comment: Avast is probably triggering on the zip or gz quines that we have in our unit tests.